# jqGrid data to HTML5 localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is there a way to get back the jqGrid data to HTML5 localStorage after an edit in place?

Comment: Which editing mode you use ([inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing), [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) or [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing))?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the editurl to the string "clientArray", you can process the data locally in the aftersave function. For example:

```
$('#table').jqGrid('saveRow', 1, $.noop, 'clientArray', {}, function($t, rowid) {
    // save to local storage here
}
```

$t in this instance appears to be the table object itself. The source for saveRow() is in src/grid.{cell,inline,form}edit.js.